# Foundation abide. Validation does not occur with blank values on required field

Tags: zurb-foundation, abide

I have this:

```
<input id="surname" type="text" name="surname" required pattern="alpha_numeric"/>
            <span id="surname_error" class="form-error">
                You need to enter a surname
            </span>
```

If I put a value in there, and then erase it, it will show the error as expected.

If however, I land on that field (either from tab, or by clicking) and then tab, or click on to another field, the error is not shown.

This behaviour is also displayed on the abide documentation page:

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/abide.html

Check the "Password Required" field after the Abide demo html block. If you tab out of it, without having entered a value. The corresponding error is not shown. How do I change the behaviour so that a required field, shows the corresponding error, when loosing focus, irrespective of whether a value was in there previously?

Thanks in advance

Dylan